# How to Link to mosquitto lib in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I have installed `mosquitto lib` in my Rpi using this [tutorial](https://www.disk91.com/2013/technology/hardware/mqtt-on-raspeberry-pi/).
`/usr/local/bin` has `mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub` and the mosquitto server deamon is in `/usr/local/sbin`.

Then trying to link the library in my cmake file as follow.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
 
PROJECT(MosquittoTest)
# The version number.
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Linked libariries
#For MQTT
#location of raspicam's cmake file is /usr/src/raspicam-0.1.3/build
link_directories(/usr/local/sbin)
target_link_libraries (MosquittoTest  mosquitto)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MosquittoTest MosquittoTest.cpp)

# add the install targets
install (TARGETS MosquittoTest DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES MosquittoInterface.h DESTINATION include)
```

Then I have error as Can't specify link library for target MosquittoTest.

Somebody has link the mosquitto lib in gcc make as

```make
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I
DEPS = mosquitto.h

LIBS = -llibmosquitto

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

make: test.c
    $(CC) -m32 -Wall -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
```

What could be wrong with my cmake file?

Comment: Now it is solved. I need to install libmosquittoop-dev into my system.

Comment: an alternative solution is to use conan to pull in mosquitto rather than require a debian package install i.e. mosquitto/1.6.12 make sure you put mosquitto:shared=True in the [options] section of the conanfile.txt so you'll have a library to link against. Then just put mosquitto in target_link_libraries and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Modern CMake, you can use pkg-config imported targets like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(MosquittoTest VERSION 0.1)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(Mosquitto IMPORTED_TARGET libmosquitto REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MosquittoTest.cpp MosquittoInterface.h)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
target_link_library(${PROJECT_NAME} PkgConfig::Mosquitto)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
install(FILES MosquittoInterface.h DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

All compile options, link options, link targets, etc... will be set for you.

Comment: does it depend on specific libmosquitto-dev version? On ubuntu 18, it seems that the default libmosquitto-dev does not provide pkg-config support

Comment: @FelixXu Yes it does depend. You could also use [Conan](https://conan.io/) to greatly facilitate your integration.

Answer (score 0):

The mosquitto library is called mosquitto not libmosquitto.

```make
JimsFridge: JimsFridge.cpp StopWatch.cpp
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ -lwiringPi -lstdc++ -lmosquitto
```